# Allowing NodeJS and Express to handle Cache-Control headers

Tags: node.js, express

I have a server in nodeJS responsible to serve some resources via REST.

Lately one of the consumer of the API started adding on the header this:         **"Cache-Control": "no-cache"**

Node reject the preflight options with a: 
*Request header field Cache-Control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers* error.

I don't have a problem with that. But i'm not sure where I can allowed this in Express.

This how my express middleware looks like

```
 app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'my-header,X-Requested-With,content-type,Authorization');
  //res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
  // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

  res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
  res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
  res.setHeader("Expires", "0"); // Proxies.

  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

And here I am with the answer.

Cache-control needs to be listed in the Access-Control-Allow-Header (surprising right, is exactly what the error was telling me). Not just on as a specific header.

So, in the code above we need to replace

`res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'my-header,X-Requested-With,content-type,Authorization');`

with

```
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'my-header,X-Requested-With,content-type,Authorization,cache-control');
```